# GWT: Remote Logging and deobfuscating the stack trace with the StackTraceDeobfuscator

Tags: java, gwt, logging

I have an issue where I am using remote logging and my stack trace is obfuscated.  I have done quite a bit of research on this, and [this blog](http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2012/06/11/7-tips-for-exception-handling-in-gwt) was probably the most helpful reference I found. However, looking at tip 5 and 6 from the blog, I get the impression that the StackTraceDeobfuscator can be used without adding the following to my GWT module

```
<set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="emulated" />
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers"
value="true" />
```

I would prefer to NOT set the compiler.stackMode property and increase the size of my javascript bundle, but I am starting to doubt it's possible.  Is the above property in fact a requirement for deobfuscating my client stack traces?  Are there any alternatives?  I want to avoid making a change that can impact the performance or security of my application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial means of providing the deobfuscated stacktrace involved reluctantly setting the properties that I mentioned in my description.

```
<set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="emulated" />
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers"
value="true" />
```

However, these new compile instructions did increase the size of my Javascript, and cause performance issues.  When using Internet Explorer 8, which some of our customers still use, there were a couple of things you could do on the website that would result in a "long running script" popup.

An important detail that I failed to mention in the description is that this issue surfaced during a GWT upgrade.

Previously, we were using `com.google.gwt.logging.server.StackTraceDeobfuscator` in a child class of GWT's `RemoteServiceServlet`.  That Deobfuscator is now deprecated and we moved to `com.google.gwt.core.server.StackTradeDeobfuscator`.  It turns out that the issue noted was tied to the symbol maps directory path that was used to attain the StackTraceDeobfuscator from the new static factory methods.  Once that was fixed, I was able to remove both the `compiler.stackMode` and the `compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers` properties, while still receiving a deobfuscated stacktrace from the client.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the same path, starting from the blog you mentioned above. However, at end of step 4, it mentions that not all exceptions are compatible with RPC(i.e. the JavascriptException). How do you pass the exception stacktrace through RPC to the backend to be able to deobfuscate it?